# Why 'xelatex' fails to find the font?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, hebrew

I'm using `xelatex` the create a PDF from a `tex` file.
Normally I use the command:

```
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{DejaVu Sans}
```

Which successfully loads the font.
Though when I try a different font it fails to load it. The code:

```
\setmainfont{Nachlieli CLM}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Nachlieli CLM}
```

Yields:

```
   (... Omitted for brevity ...)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/babel-

hebrewalph.def))kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `Nachlieli CLM', contains ' '

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Nachlieli CLM" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.11 \setmainfont{Nachlieli CLM}

? 
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `Nachlieli CLM', contains ' '

(... Omitted for brevity ...)
```

What is missing?
I'm using the font "Nachlieli CLM" with LibreOffice all the time.
Using Ubuntu 14.

**Edit #1:**
Perhaps important - the "full" tex code is:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}

\setmainfont{Nachlieli CLM}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Nachlieli CLM}
```

Comment: Please tell us a bit more about the font "Nachlieli CLM". E.g., is it a system font, or is it a font that you installed on your own?

Comment: @Mico I think that it is a system font but not sure. How do I check that? (I don't remember installing font at all, except for probably the fonts that `tex` use, via the Ubuntu Software Center)

Answer (score 0):

You can just write the name of your ttf (instead of font family name)

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    %Path = C:/Users/font/, %address of your fonts
    Extension = .ttf,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Oblique,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldOblique,
]{DejaVuSans}
%\newfontfamily{\myfont}[
    %ame as in main font
%]{myfont}
```

If it still cannot find font, it means that font is not located in system `$PATH`, so you must specify address, or just put those fonts in the same directory, where is your `.tex` file.

Comment: How do I find the name of the ttf of the "Nachlieli CLM" font?

Comment: If the font is in your system, then it should have "nachlieli" in its name. Or you can search web for this font. normally they are in .rar or .zip

Comment: I've already searched it in `/usr/share` and `~` but failed to find it. I thought that maybe it has a different name. Where else could it be stored? The libreoffice program uses it..

Comment: Unlike windows linux stores system fonts in various places. I think you should search it in $PATH address. If I remember correctly command: `echo $PATH` shows system paths.

Comment: I executed `sudo find / -iname 'nachlieli'` but it didn't find anything.

Comment: Please see my #1 edit, does it help?

Comment: I think this is a PostScript type 1 font. I think you'll get much better behaviour for Hebrew with a good OpenType font. Your search isn't finding the font because you need to glob. Try `find / -iname 'nachieli*'`. Perhaps someone else can show how to actually use a `afm` and `pfa` font pair with `fontspec`.

Comment: @Dor:  you can try `fc-list | grep "Nachlieli"`